# Why doesn't the comment show, when I use structure command in R

Tags: r, attributes, structure

This is the code:

```
structure(1:5 , comment="my_attr")
```

The output is [1] 1 2 3 4 5, the question is why is attribute missing?

Comment: From [`?comment`](https://rdrr.io/r/base/comment.html): *"Contrary to other attributes, the comment is not printed (by print or print.default)"*.

Answer (score 2):

It's in there, even though it's not printed:

```
a <- structure(1:5 , comment="my_attr")
str(a)
attr(a, "comment")
```

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from the help page of `comment` (`?comment`), you'll find the following sentence.

> Contrary to other attributes, the comment is not printed (by print or print.default).

If you want `structure` to `print` the `attributes` on the fly, use `attributes` instead of `comment`.

```r
structure(1:5, attributes = "my_attr")
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
#attr(,"attributes")
#[1] "my_attr"

#To display attributes only 
attributes(structure(1:5, attributes = "my_attr"))
#$attributes
#[1] "my_attr
```

You can also wrap your original line inside `attributes()` to `print` the attribute set by `comment` as follows `attributes(structure(1:5, attributes = "my_attr"))`